# Ros2 Controller Manager inavailable for spawner

Tags: ros-humble, ros2-control

Recently I upgraded from `Foxy` to `Humble`. When launching my application the `controller_manager` reports:

```
[Deprecated] Passing the robot description parameter directly to the control_manager node is deprecated. Use '~/robot_description' topic from 'robot_state_publisher'
```

However, if I do in fact remove the robot description from the node parameters, so that the `control_manager` is listening on the topic, and I use the `spawner` helper script to spawn my controllers, they will all time out.

```
[joint_state_broadcaster_spawner]: Controller manager not available
```

Since it is only a warning for now, I'm going to ignore that, because doing it the 'old' way does not raise any problems. It could bite me in the future, has someone a solution for that issue?

Answer (score 0):

It is a deprecation warning and behavior changed already on rolling, but won't be backported to humble.

Can you give more context of the logfile of launching without parameter? In which state is the controller manager?